# Split echo's output on two lines

Tags: command-line, echo

It is written in the manual that `/n` will split the output of echo command to the next line. I tried:

```
echo -e 'hello /n world'
hello /n world
```

Expecting 'world' on the next line. I failed.

Comment: In which manual is it written that /n will do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your mistake is to use `/n` instead of `\n`.

So just try `echo -e 'hello \nworld'` and you will get what you expect.

Notice that I have removed the space between `\n` and `world`. Else the second line will start with a space.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` is new line not `/n`

You should try this:

```
echo -e 'hello \n world'
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man echo`:

```
   -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

   -E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)

   If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:

   \\     backslash

   \a     alert (BEL)

   \b     backspace

   \c     produce no further output

   \e     escape

   \f     form feed

   \n     new line

   \r     carriage return

   \t     horizontal tab

   \v     vertical tab

   \0NNN  byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)

   \xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)

   NOTE: your shell may have its own version of echo, which usually supersedes the version described here. Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.
```

Please note the NOTE :) For example in `sh` there is no option `-e` for `echo`:

```
$ sh -c "echo -e 'hello \n world'"
-e hello 
world
```

You can see `-e` is output as regular text but the backslash escape is interpreted as it is expected.

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward alternative is to use manifest line feeds in the quoted string,

```
echo "hello
world"
```

If you want to see the alignment, press enter after the first quotation character

```
echo "
hello beautiful
wonderful world"
```

and remove that line feed to avoid a blank first line of the output.